# How to query object of object with keys in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

My ES doc is as below

```
"available_at": {
  "4": {
     "is_active": true,
     "city": "Mumbai",
     "item_id": 4,                      
    },
  "6": {
     "is_active": true,
     "city": "Delhi",
     "item_id": 6,                      
    }
}
```

I want to query this field based on multiple item_id like below

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must":[
          {
             "term": {
                "available_at": ["5","6"]
             }
          },
        ]
      }
   }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, can you please suggest.

Comment: Please add index mapping to the ques. This looks like a nested object

Comment: @TusharShahi I didn't understand